# How do I use a UVmap in renderman for Blender?

Tags: uv, renderman-render-engine

I am trying to render a model created using cycles in Renderman but the UV map doesn't show up.  Can anyone help me use the uv map please?

Comment: What do you mean the UV map doesn't show up? UV maps are not visible entities by themselves. Also have in mind that materials created for one render engine are not compatible with materials for other engines.

Answer (score 2):

The UV maps work the exact same in Renderman as they do in Cycles. However there is something to be aware of.

You must have the image texture node loaded with the image to view it in the UV editor. (Do not have the node connected to anything just have it in the node editor by itself).

Also make sure you click "convert cycles materials to renderman materials" in the materials tab. (They wont copy exactly but it will get you started).

[image]